# PHP Multiple Update function not updating and gets the 1st row blank

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, variables, dreamweaver

First of all, I use PHP Dreamweaver to make a program with phpMyAdmin Database. This program gets my records in a 1st row blank when I submit the button, and the remaining records in a rows are still there which is 2nd row and below, but the records in a 1st row is still on the database, why should it happen? any idea for me to solve this program, it also won't update my record. this makes me sick, i need help please! :(
tnx...

this is the code:

```
<?php require_once('Connections/tlsc_conn.php');
  mysql_select_db($database_tlsc_conn, $tlsc_conn);
  $query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM tbl_name";
  $Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $tlsc_conn) or die(mysql_error());
  $row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
  $totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);

  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
      $count = count($_POST['id']);
      $submit = $_GET['id'];

      for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
          $sql1="UPDATE $tbl_name SET name='$name[$i]', lastname='$lastname[$i]', email='$email[$i]' WHERE id='$id[$i]'";
          $row_Recordset1=mysql_query($sql1);
       }

    if($row_Recordset1){
            header("location:lulu.php");
            exit;
    }   
 }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org    /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
 <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form name="form2" method="post" action="">
  <table width="634" border="1">
    <tr>
       <td>id</td>
       <td>name</td>
       <td>lastname</td>
       <td>email</td>
    </tr>
   <?php do { ?> 
    <tr>
      <td><?php $id[]=$row_Recordset1['id']; ?><?php echo $row_Recordset1['id']; ?> 
      <input name="id[]" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['id'];   ?>" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="name[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['name']; ?>">                       
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="lastname[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['lastname']; ?>">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="email[]" type="text" value="<?php echo  $row_Recordset1['email']; ?>">       </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)); ?>  
   </table>
    <p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </p>
  </form>
   <p>
   </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where do you set `$name`, `$lastname`, etc.?

Comment: Are you missing `$name = $_POST['name'];`, etc.?

Comment: And what are you doing to protect against SQL injection?

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: it's just a query, what injection?

Comment: Google it: http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: i tried many time, but this website, maybe someone can help me

Comment: If you want help with your code, answer the questions.

Comment: SQL Injection -

Many web developers are unaware of how SQL queries can be tampered with, and assume that an SQL query is a trusted command. It means that SQL queries are able to circumvent access controls, thereby bypassing standard authentication and authorization checks, and sometimes SQL queries even may allow access to host operating system level commands.

Comment: Let's not spend a lot of time on SQL injection. Your question was about how to do updates. Do you want help with that or not?

Comment: first of all i'm using phpmyadmin as the database,i set the $name and $lastname and $email there.and i'm using dreamweaver for this, do i have to use $name = $_POST['name'];

Comment: You can't set PHP variables in phpmyadmin, it just lets you update the database. You're confusing PHP variables with database columns.

Comment: so what will i do for that?:(

Answer (score 1):

You need to put:

```
$name = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_POST['name']);
$lastname = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_POST['lastname']);
$email = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_POST['email']);
$id = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_POST['id']);
```

before your `for` loop. You're using these variables but you never filled them in from the form inputs.

Comment: you mean I'm going to add this code inside the {for} loop without removing something?tnx for this effort.

Comment: i tried, but still gets my first row record blank when i submit :(

Comment: I can't explain it, I think it should work. Try echoing the `UPDATE` statements to see what's being executed.